# What do you call an "item" with all its "subsidiaries" in a museum?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Since I don't know the answer, I'm having a hard time writing the question...

An **artifact** is a specific object. I want the name of the artifact (if existent) and the plaque describing it, and the video, etc.

An **exhibit**, while used in courts (at least on TV) to describe one item, seems to be used in museums to describe a group of items.

A **display**?

Something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be, in fact, an ***exhibit***.

**exhibit** (from [the online dictionary](http://dictionary.com))

9. something that is exhibited.
10. an object or a collection of objects shown in an exhibition, fair, etc.

Same as *Ausstellen* in German, if you're wondering.